# Consideration of centrifugal force during descent

Tags: rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force

If we imagine an object falling from a height h above the surface of the earth. We can go into a rotating frame and therefore introduce Coriolis and centrifugal forces.

Using the Coriolis force the deflection in the East-West Plane can be calculated. However, I am wondering does the centrifugal force influence the trajectory of the particle? Therefore, introducing some displacement in the North-South Plane.

To summarise my question is:

Does the centrifugal force cause objects to deflect when they fall , when considered in the rotating frame?

I have never seen it introduced into this type of question and therefore I am tempted to say it doesn't. However, I can not think of why this would be true.

Comment: Titles should not have every work capitalized. I edited the title for you. See [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) with information about writing good titles.

Answer (score 0):

You're presumably talking about objects dropped away from the equator. At the equator it causes a lower effective gravity. Away from the equator it causes a deflection towards the equator.